# When I duplicate multiple objects they are still linked

Tags: objects, object-mode, select

Pretty self-explanatory. I have some toilets and stalls that I duplicated and linked so that I can adjust them as I go. I want to duplicate some of these objects without linking them but the only way I can do that is one by one, otherwise, they are still linked. This is incredibly frustrating.

Answer (score 3):

In Object Mode, **either** <kbd>F3</kbd> Search > 'Make Single User', **or** Header > Object Menu > Relations > 'Make Single User' .. will offer you options for the type of data block to unlink, and the span of the operation: Selected, or All.

Comment: You got it right on the mark! Thank you